# Why does my app designed with kivy doesn't have access to the internet?

Tags: python, kivy, pytube

Recently I created an application with python by using the kivy module. It is a YouTube to mp3 converter/downloader app. It works absolutely fine and as expected when I run the code on VS. However, once I convert the file from .py to .apk, there is a bug... The issue on the app is that when you paste the link in the input bar and click on the 'submit' button to convert, it doesn't download the video.

I've added some try/except clauses in order to spot the line which is causing an issue to download a vid. I found it on line 70 : it turns out my app cannot browse the streams available for a video. After experimenting with the code on VS, I discovered that an error is happening due to line 70 when my laptop is disconnected from the internet too. That's why I think that the issue is that my app can't access the internet. I uncommented the line granting the internet permission to the app on the buildozer.spec file but it doesn't work anyways and showed the same line was causing a problem.

A snippet from the .py file including the line 70 is below:

```
                try: # browse and select the stream

                    vid = yt.streams.filter(only_audio=True).first() # this is causing the problem

                    try:# download the vid 

                        output_file = vid.download(r'''Internal storage/Download''')

                        try: # change the exctension

                            base,ext=os.path.splitext(output_file)
                            new_file = base+'.mp3'
                            os.rename(output_file, new_file)
                            self.verification.text=f'download successful new file created at: {new_file}'

                        except:
                            self.verification.text="download unsuccesful; problem with os module"

                    except:
                        self.verification.text="download unsuccesful; can't download vid"


                except:
                    self.verification.text="download unsuccesful, can't select stream"
```

Comment: Have you made the request for the app to access internet?

Comment: Using a bare `except:` that does not print the actual error is a bad idea, because it hides the error.  The error could be anything at all.  For example, in the innermost `except`, you're assuming that the error was due to the os module.  But what if it was actually something completely different?  You'll never know, because the except block deliberately hides those details.

Comment: You need to provide a [mre] and debugging details such as Android logs.

Comment: @PandaBlue Yes, I did uncomment the line for requirements and left INTERNET in the buildozer.spec file.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thanks for taking interest in my issue. I'll make sure to spot that precise error happening in my code :) Happy new year !